# Generalizing an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have this problem:

```
beta(1) = b(1);
beta(2) = b(2) - a(1)*beta(1)
beta(3) = b(3) - a(1)*beta(2) - a(2)*beta(1)
beta(4) = b(4) - a(1)*beta(3) - a(2)*beta(2)- a(3)*beta(1)
.
.
.
beta(n) = b(n) - a(1)*beta(n-1)....a(n-2)*beta(2) - a(n-1)*beta(1)
```

Now when I have 4 values of `b` i.e. `b(1)` to `b(4)`, then I will always have 3 values of `a` i.e. `a(1)` to  `a(3)` and I have to calculate `beta(1)` to `beta(4)`. So number of `beta`s to be calculated depends on number of values of `b`.

I cannot hard-code it as there are 1000s of values to be calculated. How do I generalize it, i.e. how can I programmatically obtain all values for given `b`, `a` and arbitary `n`?

Comment: You have already generalized: `beta(n) = b(n) - a(1)*beta(n)......a(n-2)*beta(2) - a(n-1)*beta(1)` ... what do you want now ?

Comment: i think he further want to put values of beta(1), beta(2)..etc in final statement.

Comment: The formula that I generalized, I can't just put it there because there are different number of terms to be calculated for every `beta`.

Comment: Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: Please specify _explicitly_ what result(s) you need: is it just `beta(n)` or `beta(0)` to `beta(n)`?

Comment: @greybeard Is correct. My answer is fine if you need `BETA(1)` through `BETA(N)`, but is sub-optimal if you only need `BETA(N)`.

Comment: @greybeard `beta(1)` to `beta(n)`  dependent on the number of values of `b` as also mentioned in the question

Comment: Do you need all of them, or just the last one?

Comment: ***ALL OF THEM*** @greybeard

Comment: (`ALL OF THEM` great. No need to yell: Put that _in the question_ ([edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41358196/edit)) instead of commenting a comment asking for additional information or clarification.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it with an array and clever running through the variables.
Code in Java (please note that Java starts indexing with 0, not 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < beta.length; i++) {
    beta[i] = b[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        beta[i] = beta[i] - a[j]*beta[i-j-1];
    }
}
```

then you have

```
beta[0] == b[0]
beta[1] == b[1] - a[0]*beta[0]
beta[2] == b[2] - a[0]*beta[1] - a[1]*beta[0]
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

A solution that seems to be efficient to me would be some form of memoized recursion with `b` as a vector. Here is my pseudo-code implementation

```
MEMO := ALLOCATE(LENGTH(B))
DEFINE BETA(N)
    IF N = 1
        RETURN B[1]
    ELSE IF MEMO[N] != 0
        RETURN MEMO[N]
    ELSE
        MEMO[N] := B[N]

        FOR I IN 1 TO N - 1
            MEMO[N] := MEMO[N] - A[I]*BETA[N-I]
        END FOR

        RETURN MEMO[N]
    END IF
END DEFINE
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. :)